# I am trying to get the punctuation removed from my data. The ".str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')" is not working. what can I do? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have:

```
df['lowercase'] = df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(word.lower() for word in x.split()))
```

this works just fine the issue is here:

```
df['lowercase'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')
```

the punctuation isn't being removed. The `df['reviews']` is a before (has punctuation and has uppercase). Then in the next image its supposed to be lowercase (which it is) and has no punctuation.

[photo of a before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkbx9.png)

Tried changing the forward slash to backslash... didn't work. Have tried import re and import string, not working as well

Comment: ** still has punctuation... I should not have any

Comment: `replace` does not operate in place, you need to assign the result

Comment: Do you not need to reassign the result of df['lowercase'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', '') to another variable?

Comment: @Nick Tried it, not working. Still getting the same output. The punctuation is still there.

Comment: @SGandhi yes. I have reassigned it to `df['punc]`. It now looks like this:
' df['punc'] = df['lowercase'].str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s]', '') '

Comment: @DoubleThink sorry, forgot the all important `regex=True`: `df['lowercase'] = df['reviews'].str.lower().str.replace(r'[^\w\s]', '', regex=True)` https://ideone.com/C7CdSy

Comment: Note you don't need to use `.str.lower()` on `df['lowercase']` as you've already lowercased it. My code does both lower case and punctuation removal in one step.

Comment: @Nick it works! Thank you. Was just missing the regex=True. Mind explaining what that does? And also, what is '[^\w\s]' considered? Isnt it regular expression? Is there a link or database that I can see for more python "secret coding" I also have lowercase separated just to compare reviews, lowercase, and punctuation :).. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, `[^\w\s]` is a regular expression, and in older versions of pandas `str.replace` would assume it was one. However that behaviour changed and you now have to explicitly specify `regex=True` to get the pattern string treated as a regex. Note that whenever you use a regex you should use a raw string (i.e. `r'...'`) to ensure that it gets interpreted properly. As for "secret coding", you can't go past the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html)

Comment: @Nick for "secret coding" I meant like where can I find the regular expressions list?

Comment: @DoubleThink there's a good reference on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean, you can also use sites like https://regex101.com to test regexes - it has a good explanation of what your regex matches on the side. There's also sites like https://regular-expressions.info and https://www.rexegg.com/ for learning.